# Setting up and solving a recurrence relation for a recursive function?

Tags: math, recursion, big-o, recurrence

I am in the process of learning java recurrence but am stuck on the following question.

```
void f(int n) {
    if (n<=1) return;
    f(n/2);
    System.out.writeln("still continuing...");
    f(n/2);
    f(n/2);
}
```

I have two questions about this.

1. if we say that T(n) is the number of lines that the program prints and n is the input, what would be the recurrence formula for T(n)?
2. How do I go about solving the recurrence from question 1 without using master theorem?

cheers

Comment: Please do not abuse the tags field.

Comment: The tags you previously posted had nothing to do with this question, which is about algorithms and not programming languages.  I replaced those with tags appropriate to an algorithms problem.

Comment: sorry I didn't know what to fill the other 4 tags with as this is only recursion.

Comment: no, im learning from a book called Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity, but its not very clear.

Comment: Why is T(n) the number of lines? What is T in this case? Is that your time complexity or space complexity?  You have three recursions and each time you halve it. You can try draw the recursion tree if this is a simple problem. When I look at T I think of it as time complexity, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: i'm assuming its time complexity but like I said the book only briefly covers this. not a very good book.

Comment: if n is the power 2, am I right in thinking the recurrence formula is T(2)=n2+1

Comment: Look at the number of recursive calls you are making. That's 3. The size of the recursive call is 1/2 each time. There is no merging involve. The cost of dividing and printing out the statement is O(1) which is constant. That's your f(n). The general recurrence relation is T(n) = aT(n/b)+f(n) where a is # of supproblems and b is the size of the division. The recurrence relation is `T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(1)`.

Comment: thanks, can you point me to any clear guides on-line on how to solve that recursion?

Comment: You don't actually have to use all 5 tags.

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin with a formula for the value of T(n).  We know the following:

1. Calling f with 0 or 1 as arguments takes time O(1)
2. Calling f with a larger value makes three calls to f(n / 2), and does a constant amount of other work.

Consequently, we can get the following recurrence:

- T(1) ≤ 1
- T(n) ≤ 3T(n / 2) + 1

Notice that I'm using a "+ 1" term here instead of a "+ O(1)" term.  This is mathematically iffy, but since we're looking for a final result expressed in big-O notation anyway, this will not be too much of a problem.

Now, how would we go about trying to solve this?  One option would be to plug in some arbitrary value for n and see what happens.  We begin with (assuming n > 1) that

> T(n) ≤ 3T(n / 2) + 1

Now, let's think about those calls to T(n / 2).  If n / 2 > 1, then we get that

> T(n) ≤ 3T(n / 2) + 1
>
> ≤ 3(3T(n / 4) + 1) + 1
>
> = 9T(n / 4) + 3 + 1

Now, let's expand this out a gain:

> T(n) ≤ 9T(n / 4) + 3 + 1
>
> ≤ 9(3T(n / 8) + 3) + 3 + 1
>
> = 27T(n / 8) + 9 + 3 + 1

At this point, we can see a pattern emerging.  After i iterations of the recursion, we have that the total work done is

> T(n) = 3<sup>i</sup>T(n / 2<sup>i</sup>) + sum(i = 0 to i - 1)3<sup>i</sup>

This process terminates when n / 2<sup>i</sup> ≤ 1, which occurs when i ≈ lg n.  If we plug in lg n, we get

> T(n) ≤ 3<sup>lg n</sup>T(1) + sum(i = 0 to i - 1)3<sup>i</sup>)
>
> ≤ 3<sup>lg n</sup> + sum(i = 0 to i - 1)3<sup>lg n</sup>

Now, 3<sup>lg n</sup> = 3<sup>(log3 n / log3 2)</sup> = 3<sup>log3 n<sup>1 / log3 2</sup></sup> = n<sup>1 / log3 2</sup>, so this entire thing is

> T(n) ≤ n<sup>1 / log3 2</sup> + sum(i = 0 to (lg n) - 1)3<sup>i</sup>

Using the formula for sums of geometric series, this last term is (3<sup>lg n</sup> - 1) / 2, which ends up expanding out to O(n<sup>1 / log3 2</sup>), so overall this expression is O(n<sup>1 / log<sub>3</sub> 2</sup>).

But this formula is really ugly.  Can we simplify it?  Well, we do have this:

> 1 / log<sub>3</sub> 2 = log<sub>2</sub> 3

Which gives us that the runtime is O(n<sup>lg 3</sup>), which is about O(n<sup>1.58</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) = 3* T(n/2)+ O(1)
```

As the theorem indicates, the answer should be O(n^(lg 3)).

For more details, you can refer to the Introduction to Algorithm by Cormen et, see chapter 4.
The solving of recurrance equations are quite complicated. But normally the method is first guess, then prove using substitution.

Comment: I think that the OP's question is, specifically, how to solve this without using the Master THeorem.  Though the CLRS reference is definitely great!